# How do I convert a Simple Integer to a time's Minutes

Tags: python, datetime

I have this integers here `i = 33` and `o = 156`, what i want to do is to convert these integers into minutes in a time format to become these results:

```
i => 00:33:00
o => 02:36:00
```

i tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

i = 33
o = 156

itime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=i)
itime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=o)
```

and it gives me this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

which is solved by adding `import datetime`

but in my code it breaks some parts of it like `datetime.strptime()` when i add it like this

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

also i tried without the `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` like this `datetime.timedelta(minutes=33)` but the result was

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 1980)
```

but i want it to be by minutes and not seconds like this `datetime.time(0, 33)`

Comment: Divide by 60, maybe?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I would do that, But the main problem for me before that is that after typing the two imports, i can't use function like `datetime.strptime()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amend the above code to this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

i = 33
o = 156

itime = timedelta(minutes=i)
itime = timedelta(minutes=o)
```

You already imported `timedelta`, so you do not need to call it as a child library from `datetime`. The additional `datetime` import overrides the child library import.

Not sure why you use `itime` twice though it would override the first one as well...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
x = datetime.time(0,0) + timedelta(minutes=i)
```

Comment: I keep getting `TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'`, the problem seems in my importing way of packages.

Comment: you might need to `import time` too

Comment: like this 'from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time'? still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
def convert_to_minutes(i):
    hr = i // 60
    m = i - hr * 60
    res_ = str(hr) + ":" + str(m) + ":" + "00"
    res = datetime.strptime(res_, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    return res
```